# Как расположить каждую ссылку под конкретной фотографией и сделать текст ссылок в 3 ряда?

Tags: html, css

```
 <div class="work__types">
        <img src="/IMG/example-1.png" alt="Example" class="works">
        <img src="/IMG/example-2.png" alt="Example" class="works">
        <img src="/IMG/example-3.png" alt="Example" class="works">
        <img src="/IMG/example-4.png" alt="Example" class="works">
        <img src="/IMG/example-5.png" alt="Example" class="works">
    </div>
    <div class="work__nav">
        <a href="#" class="works__links">Деревянное остекление</a>
        <a href="#" class="works__links">Алюминиевое остекление</a>
        <a href="#" class="works__links">Остекление пластиковыми рамами</a>
        <a href="#" class="works__links">Французское остекление (панорамное)</a>
        <a href="#" class="works__links">Остекление с выносом</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: обернуть  нужную картинку и нужную ссылку в li и всё

Answer (score 0):

- `.wrapper` - враппер всех блоков,
- `.block` - блок картинка + ссылка,
- `.block__description` описание блока,
- `.block__list` список ссылок.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.block {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.block__list {
list-style:none;
padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block">
        <img src="/IMG/example-1.png" alt="Example" class="works">
        <div class="block__description">Деревянное остекление</div>
        <ul class="block__list">
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <img src="/IMG/example-2.png" alt="Example" class="works">
        <div class="block__description">Алюминиевое остекление</div>
        <ul class="block__list">
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block">
        <img src="/IMG/example-3.png" alt="Example" class="works">
        <div class="block__description">Остекление пластиковыми рамами</div>
        <ul class="block__list">
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <img src="/IMG/example-4.png" alt="Example" class="works">
        <div class="block__description">Французское остекление (панорамное)</div>
        <ul class="block__list">
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block">
        <img src="/IMG/example-5.png" alt="Example" class="works">
        <div class="block__description">Остекление с выносом</div>
        <ul class="block__list">
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="works__links">link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы было пять картинок, а под ними их описание, но чтобы это описание было с фиксируемой шириной 
Например:
      Французское -1строчка

       остекление 2 строчка
    (панорамное) 3 строчка
Пытался сделать через display flex и justify-content space-between, фото выстраиваются как надо, а вот с ссылками беда

Comment: @Skiper дополнил. Не очень понятно, вам нужно описание и под ним список из 3х ссылок. Или просто 3 ссылки под картинками?  Если нужны просто 3 ссылки, то удалите div с классом .block__description

Comment: Картинки, а под ними описание.
Вот эти виды остекления должны быть ссылками, т.е Остекление с выносом - это одна ссылка под соответствующей картинкой, только эти ссылки строчные и идут в одну строчку, а мне нужно каждую ссылку сделать как-будто в стихотворной манере, каждое слово ссылки на другой строчке

Comment: @Skiper используйте тег <br> перед словом, которое хотите перенести, либо используйте строки списка, который уже есть в примере.

Comment: Большое спасибо